# How did Newt manage to catch a Nundu?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

We know that Newt has a Nundu:

> *The camera pans up to reveal another magnificent creature, the Nundu - looking almost exactly like a lion, it has a large mane that bursts forth when it roars.* 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

But we also know that Nundus are extremely hard to catch:

> This East African beast is arguably the most dangerous in the world. A gigantic leopard that moves silently despite its size and whose breath causes disease virulent enough to eliminate entire villages, it has never yet been subdued by fewer than **a hundred skilled wizards working together**
>  <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

So how did Newt manage to catch one? He usually doesn't work with others...

Comment: I am guessing ***magic.***

Comment: @Lexible Based on the entry from *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, we might additionally guess **a hundred wizards** using magic!

Comment: @jpmc26 - Most of the time he seems to use the magic of tilting his head slightly and smiling like discount-Hugh Grant.

Comment: He had a spare Pokeball, obviously :-). How else will he catch them all?

Answer (score 13):

Newt's entire schtick is that other wizards are morons when it comes to subduing and taming supposedly *wild* animals. It's pretty clear that if you go in all <s>guns</s> wands blazing against a creature as powerful as the Nundu that you're going to get your butt kicked unless you're mob-handed. On the other hand, if you take some time to understand the creature and use kindness rather than aggression, you're likely to see better results.

Although she's referring to the Zouwu (another supposedly untameable wild animal) in [this interview](https://twitter.com/i/status/1022405139775283200), JKR's quote here seems relevant.

> It really does takes a '*Newt Scamander*' to contain and look after that
>   beast

And we see from this excerpt from the Wonderbook: Book of Spells game that a Nundu (if taken *off guard*) can be put to sleep by a single wizard.

As to its supposedly murderous breath, you can see from the image below that Newt is able to walk within feet of the creature without dying. It may well be that this 'deadly breath' ability is either entirely apocryphal or some sort of defensive mechanism, in the same way that a dragon *can* breathe fire, but doesn't *always* breathe fire.

[image]

Comment: how? at first it must have been agressive, and it's breath is pretty much lethal...

Comment: so I would (personally) discredit the idea that he got to know it..

Comment: @Niffler - We see it roaring at Newt in the case and its breath seems to be very much **non**-lethal. Presumably it uses its *lethal magical breath* as a defence mechanism only when attacked, possibly in the same way that a skunk squirts a noxious fluid when it's scared. Since Newt wouldn't be dumb enough to attack it, he need not fear its breath

Comment: @Niffler - Also, in Wonderbook we see someone who *lives* with a Nundu. Admittedly it eats him, but its breath seems fine

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer! :) It might take a hundred skilled wizards to subdue a Nundu, but only one Newt to get a Nundu to like him and cooperate willingly! :)

Comment: I agree with Niffler, just by breathing, it should have killed Newt, because it's breath is supposedly poisonous enough to wipe out whole villages

Comment: @Mr.DancingMan - Indeed, and yet we see that it doesn't. **Newt walks right past it.** Clearly the 'murder-breath' is in some way selective or everything inside the case would be dead already

Comment: @Mr.DancingMan - You might also want to note that the person who wrote that is none other than Newt himself, presumably wanting to discourage people from approaching this fearsome but otherwise innoccuous beastie

Comment: @Valorum newt walks ***by*** it thus it couldn't get close to breathing on him without ***turning around*** ,thus i also think this added part is irrelevant.

Comment: @niffler - He's within inches of it, trying to feed it. If its breath was truly deadly, don't you think he'd have been using some kind of protection, magical or otherwise

Comment: this looks more like *feet* to me, but alright

Comment: @niffler - I'm struggling to understand why this answer is upsetting to you. Are you looking for confirmation that this was some sort of writing error?

Comment: and if it's breath wasn't deadly why wouldn't he simply bring the food straight to the creatures mouth

Comment: @Niffler - Probably for the same reason lion feeders don't hold food in their hands, because that's the best way to get mauled

Comment: I just think that saying that he tamed it with kindness is well *eh*

Comment: @Niffler - That's how he tames *all* of his animals. Through kindness and understanding. He's occasionally firm, but never angry or vindictive

Comment: first he traps them... then he's kind to them